# Problem with dropdown bootstrap not showing up properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

The items of the dropdown menu are not displaying properly.What should I do ? The website is working good on the mobile phone(the nav part) but on the pc it's crappy. Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" id="butonuldinnav" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">A
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">X</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Y</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

**ORDER**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
```

Images :
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhaA7.png)

[if I scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mxWC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<nav class="navbar-inverse navbar-nav navbar-header">
  <div id="butonuldinnav" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#myNavbar">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </div>
  <ul class="collapse navbar-nav" id="myNavbar">
      <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle='collapse' aria-expanded='false' data-bs-target='#A'>
          A <i class="caret"></i></a>
        <ul id='A' class="collapse">
          <li><a href="#">sub-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">sub-2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Links and script:

```
<link href='https://bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://bootstrap.bundle.min.js'/>
<link href="https://font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: I've tried it even on a new page, but doesn't work